# What is the point of prescriptive grammar?

Tags: grammar

There seems to be a distinction and even rift between [descriptive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description) and [prescriptive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) grammar, though wikipedia points out that they can apparently "inform each other":

> Despite apparent opposition, prescription and description can inform each other,[3][page needed] because comprehensive descriptive accounts must take into account speaker attitudes (including prescriptive ones), and some understanding of how language is actually used is necessary for prescription to be effective.

But I've just never really understood prescriptive grammar -- it seems like language is constantly being added to (and to a lesser extent, losing some words because they're becoming so archaic it's not even really the same language anymore), so saying what's "right" or "wrong" in terms of grammar is basically choosing some specific moment in time and arbitrarily deciding that that's the "proper" form of the language, and the one to strive for.

It just seems like an inherently losing battle, and one that makes no sense to fight -- if 100% of people understand a word, what's the point in saying it shouldn't be used? E.g., "I ain't" is definitely not considered correct, but there's no real reason it shouldn't be allowed as an alternative to "I'm not".

I understand one reason for prescriptive grammar, essentially to make communication possible. It essentially establishes rules, and speech would quickly get confusing if we had no rules. But some of the things it prohibits seem to have little to do with facilitating communication, and more with just upholding some arbitrary status quo. "Swag" is a really annoying word, but it doesn't really make sense to say it's not an "official word" or something if millions of people are using it and all know what it means among each other.

Why exactly do prescriptivists even really want this? Is it some sort of weak attempt at "seeking permanence in an impermanent world"?

Comment: You talk as if there were two camps, two schools, poles apart. But anyone using language will have certain prescriptivist (and probably even proscriptivist) leanings, and certain descriptivist ones. And they wouldn't even form a continuous sub-continuum on someone else's scale. Some people would be more obviously entrenched near one extreme or the other. They're the ones to avoid. Innit.

Comment: This question should be reopened. ["Primarily opinion-based" is designed to stop "What's the best X?"-type questions. It's not supposed to be used on every single question that involves opinions.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4805/what-the-primarily-opinion-based-close-reason-is-for)

Comment: @phenry, thank you. Additionally, I don't think it necessarily has to be opinion based: "What's the point of an airplane's wings?" or "What's the point of a moderator in a debate?" certainly aren't, even if they have several valid answers.

Comment: “Prescriptive grammar” is all and only about the setting of baseline normative standards, often for purposes purely paedogogical or publicational. It has nothing to do with linguistics.

Comment: @tchrist, the title of the Wikipedia page is "Linguistic Prescription". Literally the first several words of the article are "In linguistics, prescription or prescriptivism is the practice..." Whether or not you're nitpicking, it clearly has something to do with linguistics. Can people take this question off hold? People seem to have ignored the point phenry made.

Comment: Describing a language is an attempt to document it, to help people understand it. Prescription is an attempt to define a formal means of communication which is mutually intelligible when everyone follows the rules. Now, it might be that the reason a particular person wants that formality is because they seek permanence, or it might be they want it because it's convenient for everyone to roughly agree not to drop obscure localisms on each other at critical moments. So there is one purpose but no one reason for valuing that purpose.

Comment: Btw, slang words lie outside the common formal language, but don't confuse prescriptive grammar with a complete refusal *ever* to accept new vocabulary. The question for a prescriptivist to answer, then, is what grounds he or she considers sufficient to "allow" a particular word: personal taste, duration of common usage, words your parents used, origin, necessity, whatever. This isn't so very different from *describing* what vocabulary is generally considered formal/professional/polite/whatever, in that both will come to the conclusion that "ain't" is informal.

Comment: There's a confusion between what constitutes the lexis and what is considered acceptable syntax here. And discussions elsewhere on ELU about the acceptability of words-or-are-they on the do-it-yourself / me an' a few mates talk like this / everyone who uses UD knows it's a word / it's not in the OED gradience.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but it's not specifically about English. All languages can be treated prescriptively or descriptively. As such, this question would be a better fit for [linguistics.se].

Comment: Try starting at [Why is prescriptivism criticized?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/155/3571)